# BitSet stored in TreeMap always exceed its cardinality

Tags: java

The file that my program is reading contains space separated numbers such "59 23 2 84 83", if i am sure that the # "84" occur only 36 times but bitset.cardinality() report 293 times.. please help

```
static int line_counter = 0;
static TreeMap<String, BitSet> ItemsArray = new TreeMap<String, BitSet>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String[] line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt"));

    while (br.ready()) {
        line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(line);

        ItemsArray(line);

        line_counter++;

        }


    System.out.println("ItemsArray cardinality = " + ItemsArray.get("84").cardinality() + "\n");

    }


    private static void ItemsArray(String[] line) {
    BitSet temp_bitset = new BitSet();

    for (String item : line) {
        temp_bitset.clear();

        if (ItemsArray.get(item) == null) {
            temp_bitset.set(line_counter);
            ItemsArray.put(item, temp_bitset);

        } else {
            temp_bitset = (BitSet) ItemsArray.get(item).clone();
            temp_bitset.set(line_counter);
            ItemsArray.put(item, temp_bitset);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `BitSet#cardinality()` _do_?

Comment: It really doesn't help that you've got both a method *and* a variable called `ItemsArray`, neither of which is an array, and neither of which follows Java naming conventions. Additionally, we can't reproduce your problem without the exact input you're using - which could easily be hard-coded rather than using a file. We also don't know what you're trying to achieve... And to top it off, your code is badly formatted making it harder to read :(

Comment: BitSet#cardinality() is different . it doesn't say the number of time something occurred, if you want store numbers change your treemap to <String,Integer>.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that **there is only one BitSet for each line**. You then confuse matters by replacing it with one from the map if the number repeats in several lines which therefore may actually be from a different line. You then seem to clear it for no real reason. You then seem to think `clone` is the solution to all of the above problems.

Here's an idea:

```
static int line_counter = 0;
static TreeMap<String, BitSet> allBits = new TreeMap<String, BitSet>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt"));

    while (br.ready()) {
        line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(line);

        consumeItems(line);

        line_counter++;

    }

    System.out.println("ItemsArray cardinality = " + allBits.get("84").cardinality() + "\n");

}

private static void consumeItems(String[] line) {

    for (String item : line) {
        BitSet temp = allBits.get(item);
        if (temp == null) {
            temp = new BitSet();
            allBits.put(item, temp);
        }
        // Use a bit in the BitSet to indicate that this number appeared in tat line.
        temp.set(line_counter);
    }
}
```

Not sure it's what you need but it demonstrates the normal technique for creating/updating map entries.

Comment: Old Curmudgeon Although my code is badly formatted,but you get it you really helped me so thank you very much.